# How to call a function which is defined inside another function?

Tags: python

I have a function `func2` inside another function `func1`:

```
def func1():
    #something

    def func2()
        #something
        return something

    return something
```

And I want to use `func2` separately in another cell as:

```
r=func2()
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't, period.

Comment: You can't. That's the *point* of nesting it. If it should be used elsewhere, it shouldn't be a nested function (unless it gets returned, i.e. `func1` is a function factory that outputs `func2`).

Comment: try using `class` instead

Comment: @Hanz how can I use `class`

Comment: Sorry, the question has been closed, please take a look at the linked question.

Comment: *Logically* how this works is that `func2` gets defined inside the scope of `func1` *when that function is called* and it gets discarded because it goes out of scope when `func1` ends. So, it doesn't even exist if you're not inside the execution of `func1`…

Comment: ... unless something else holds onto a reference to `func2`, like when `func1` is a decorator, or if `func1` has a parameter and it attaches `func2` to that.

Comment: ☝️ Yes, if something else holds a reference to the inner function, then it's accessible elsewhere. But then you're talking about different code, and if you're talking about different code then there are many other ways to enable access to `func2`, e.g. by defining it outside `func1` in the first place…